Temporal IO running activities of a workflow outside the parent workflow JAR
I am using temporal SDKs with Java to run a temporal workflow, which has a few activities.
The last activity is to create and send a JMS message to a message queue for asynchronous processing. Since there are no steps after sending the JMS message, the temporal workflow is deemed to be completed. The process looks like this:
Temporal workflow -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 (Send JMS message)

However, once the JMS message is received by the listener component, I want to continue the steps carried out in this listener component as activities of the same temporal workflow (which ended when the message was sent to the JMS queue).
How do I continue the activities of the existing workflow from the listener JMS component once the JMS message is sent from the temporal workflow?
The process that I require is:
Temporal workflow -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 (Send JMS message)
Receive JMS message (in separate component/JAR) -> Activity 4 -> Activity 5

Reasons for using a JMS consumer for Activity 4 and 5 is to process these steps asynchronously and one at a time for multiple temporal workflow executions in the order JMS messages are received. Since the JMS consumer count is 1, a new message will not be consumed and processed until the activity 4 and 5 of the previous workflow execution are completed.
I have gone through the temporal documentation, but could not find anything to run Temporal activities outside of the code where the Temporal workflow is defined.

I guess the idea would be that your JMS consumer sends a signal to Temporal, which continues with Activity 4, 5 of the workflow. Am I missing something?

After activity 3, the temporal workflow ends, since it does not find any more activities to execute.
The activity 4,5 are in a separate jar/component

If they are not in the workflow, they are not really activities. What stops you from running them from within the JMS concumer, i.e. not from Temporal? On the other hand, if you want them to run through Temporal, why don't you place them in the same jar as the other activities? (asking to make sure I understand the problem)

The activity 4 and 5 are running from the JMS consumer, but since they are a part of the original process, I want to know their status in the same temporal workflow itself with activities 1,2,3.
The reason for not running them in the same jar is to make the architecture more modular and asynchronous, since activity 4 and 5 can take a long time to run compared to the remaining activities (upto 5-10 mins vs a few seconds for other activities) and they can run in the background. I dont want to block the whole thread to run these activities

Explained the reasons for using JMS consumer above in the question.

You don't need JMS to run activities in a separate process. Use a separate Temporal task queue for this process and schedule activities 4 and 5 to that separate task queue.
